# Mixin method call

Tags: ruby, mixins

I'm looking for something which would allow me to do something as Mongoid do:

```
class Artist
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
end
```

Basically, include a module and use a method declared in it. But I get the following error:

```
undefined method `method_name'
```

Here is the module code:

```
module Mod
  def method_name # or self.method_name results the same
  end
end
```

And here is the class code:

```
class Klass
  include Mod
  method_name 'param'
end
```

My ruby version is `2.1.2`

EDIT:

I used this in the module and it works perfectly:

```
def self.included(target)
  target.extend self
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `extend` it instead, and not use `include`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

module Task
  def method_name(*args)
  end
end

class Klass
  extend Task
  method_name :param
end
```

Comment: @JulienFouilhé See update. Since you're creating class methods, you need to extend your class instead.

Comment: Thanks, to keep the include and not use extend, I used the self.included() method as shown in my post edit.